# How to initalize/ give default value to array in defineProps when I have passed an array as a prop in vue 3 script setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-props

I have passed an array as prop items, I have given it a type in interface Props when I try to give it a default value I get an error 4th last line `TS2322: Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '(props: Readonly<Props>) => string[]'.   Type 'never[]' provides no match for the signature '(props: Readonly<Props>): string[]'.`  I am not sure what I am doing wrong here since this seems to work with other variables

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref} from "vue";

interface Props {
  items?: Array<string>
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  items: []
});
let selectedItem = ref(props.items[0])
```

Answer (score 15):

> Object or array defaults must be returned using a factory function. The factory function also receives the raw props object as the argument.

[Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#props)

This applies both to Options API and Composition API!

```js
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  items: () => []
});
```

[Reproduction](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Also how would you define it in the interface?

Comment: @SwastikAgarwal What do you want to define in interface? The default value? You can't do that in TypeScript. That's the [whole reason](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#default-props-values-when-using-type-declaration) why `withDefaults()` compiler macro exists

Comment: @SwastikAgarwal In the interface you declare it the same way that you have already  ie items?: Array<string>    or   items?: string[]

Comment: The trick is the arrow function to define the default array. () =>